# Entity Field Type symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a Dropdown Field (City), I add this filed into UserType

```
$builder->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'form.name', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'));
$builder->add('phone', 'text', array('label' => 'form.phone', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'));
$builder->add('cityId', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'form.city', 
    'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
    'class' => 'AppBundle:City',
    // 'choice_label' => 'name',
    // 'choice_value' => 'id',
));
```

But when I submit to form the cityId field sends me the City Name not the ID.
How can I fix it ?

Comment: Do you use $form->handleRequest() in your controller? Then what you get is not the city name, but the entity representing the city. That's what the entity field type is all about.

Answer (score 1):

I think property field can help you :)
In form you should add property => name

```
$builder->add('cityId', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'form.city', 
    'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
    'class' => 'AppBundle:City',
    'property' => 'name',
));
```

Or in your entity write toString function like

```
$builder->add('cityId', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'form.city', 
    'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
    'class' => 'AppBundle:City',
    // toString() function called
));
```

City.php

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```